# What was Q's rank in "Encounter at Farpoint"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-q

In the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode "Encounter at Farpoint", Q showed up dressed as a Starfleet officer.

What was his rank?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming this screenshot is correct:

[image: Q and Picard, Encounter at Farpoint]

then going by the [pips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfleet_ranks_and_insignia#The_Next_Generation.2C_Deep_Space_Nine.2C_and_Voyager) he's definitely Captain.

[Source](http://scifimusings.blogspot.com/2010/10/star-trek-tng-s1-ep1-2-encounter-at-far.html)

Comment: Kudos for the screenshot I should have thought of that...  crowd sourcing is a beautiful thing!

Comment: Based on Q's subsequent behaviors.. I'm rather surprised he didn't bump himself to Admiral, just to place him 'above' Picard.

Comment: Q: I present myself to thee as a fellow ship captain, that thou mayst better understand me. Go back whence thou camest. (to Helmsman) Stay where thou art! 
 (And the helmsman is frozen solid, phaser in hand) 
 PICARD: Data, call medics. 
 TROI: He's frozen. 
 PICARD: He would not have injured you. Do you recognise this, the stun setting? 
 Q: Knowing humans as thou dost, Captain, wouldst thou be captured helpless by them? Now, go back or thou shalt most certainly die.

Answer (score 9):

Going by timestamp 1:22:56 on the Netflix version you can see both Q and Picard standing side-by-side and their ranks are identical.  I was going to say captain off the top of my head, but I'm pretty sure that confirms it.

Edit: see Wikis' screen cap for the actual frame.

Comment: Would he be senior to Picard? :)

Comment: @DVK He was certainly older.

Comment: @Xantec: And, given that he can time travel, I'm sure he wore a Starfleet uniform before Picard was even born (or could have done so, if needed)

Comment: I thought a captain of a starship outranked other captains on the same ship.

Comment: The whole thing is a parody anyway, Q wasn't really a captain of anything as Picard mentions in the line "...if you had really earned that uniform..."